# Excel Customize Data Validation Drop downs

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am new to Excel and trying to achieve the following task but I am not able to figure out how to do it.

I have one table with category and sub category info. one category can have multiple sub categories. In table I have one row for each sub categories but I want to convert these sub categories as drop down for the respective categories.

[image]

In the `Sub Category Drop Down` column in second table on the right, I want to show drop down list for sub categories which belongs to the category value from category column from the table on the left.

How do I achieve this? Please note data in the table on the left can be added and removed and based on that table on the right should be updated.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So have a look at this and then edit it to your needs:

[image]

As cat1 or cat2 or cat3 is selected in cell A2, the range in E3 to E5 gets updated accordingly. Then the subcategory in cell B2 can be chosen.