# Dropdown in Excel

Tags: excel, dropdown

How to create a dropdown in excel so that one can select name and semester and it outputs the result from that semester.?

I created a dropdown for both name and semester but i am unable to create it for the output and link it.I want to select the name and the semester and then the result should be displayed from that semester whether the student has passed or failed the semester,i am unable to link it.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I suggest you google the XLOOKUP function

Comment: Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62742215/4961700

Comment: or this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68152019/4961700